# Facebook API - get user likes for a specific category (i.e. Music) for ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Using Facebook Graph Request, I'd like to fetch a list of the user LIKES, but only for a specific category (in my case, music).

If I do the following:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields": @"id,name,email,picture,likes"};
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:params] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    //result
};
```

I get a list of likes that looks like this:

```
{
email = "duncan@duncan.com";
id = 000058100255701;
likes =     {
    data =         (
                    {
            "created_time" = "2013-09-18T08:12:43+0000";
            id = 19292868552;
            name = "Facebook for Developers";
        }
    );
    paging =         {
        cursors =             {
            after = MTkyOTI4Njg1NTIZD;
            before = MTkyOTI4Njg1NTIZD;
        };
    };
};
}
```

However it doesn't tell me what category they belong to.

Ideally, I *only* want to see MUSIC likes.  But failing that, I would like to know the category of the like.

Is this possible?

Comment: not exact answer but may help you. [music likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/music/)

Comment: The API does not offer that kind of filtering. Getting the category as well is easy using Field Expansion syntax. [`/me?fields=likes{category,name}`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dlikes{category%2Cname}&version=v2.5)

Comment: @meth - that was the exact answer we are looking for.  Thank you!